# How do I detect wireless broadband on Ubuntu?

Tags: internet, lan, automatic

I have ubuntu 11.10, I have moved into a new house with shared Sky Broadband and I would like to know how to detect the wireless automatically as I am not sure I can get all the information required to configure it myself as the person in charge of the internet is a bit of a grumpy old **** basically. I have the password (network key?) I think (!), I just need Ubuntu to detect the wireless automatically (and connect to it automatically whenever I start my computer). Im not very computer literate, so if you answer this question please take that into consideration before speaking another language! Thanks!

Comment: You should first learn whether there's restricted settings on the Broadband.  Some "shared" networks have passcodes or logins that you would need, so you need t omake sure you have that information.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify. The subject header says you cannot detect the wireless broadband. The text says you cannot connect automatically. Do you mean to say that you can manually select the wifi network and connect, but it won't connect automatically? Or do you mean to say it does not connect at all? Is wireless network enabled in Ubuntu? If so, you should see an icon on top right. Click that icon and see if your wifi network is visible there.

Answer (score 0):

If your networks card is configured and running Ubuntu already does that. On your taskbar you can see an icon wich contains all the networks Ubuntu detects.

If you like you can try tools to better see the networks avaiable to you.

Gnome-network is one of those tools, Wicd is another.

You should give this [site](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/ubuntu-networking-configuration-using-graphical-tool.html) a read